# How do I add a border to an image in HTML?

Tags: html, css

How can I add a border to an image using HTML?

Comment: Do you mean the border http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#border-properties?

Answer (score 50):

Two ways:

```
<img src="..." border="1" />
```

or

```
<img style='border:1px solid #000000' src="..." />
```

Comment: whilst this is strictly correct in that it's HTML, a CSS approach is almost certainly the best answer

Comment: +annakata's comment. You'd also preferably place the CSS in an external style sheet.

Comment: An external style sheet is best, but may be difficult if you're a beginner. The poster seems to be one.

Comment: If you create a file with .css as the extension and then add this line between the HTML <head> tags you'll be just fine.
<link href="CSS/MyStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 47):

Here is some HTML and CSS code that would solve your issue:

**CSS**

```
.ImageBorder
{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: Black;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="MyImage.gif" class="ImageBorder" />
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to do ".ImageBorder (\nl) { (\nl) border: 1px solid #000000; (\nl)}", a la Diodeus's answer, in the CSS file.

Comment: Sounds like you may have something else going on...  Maybe competing styles?

Comment: You need to add solid to the above Css to get it to show
  border-style:solid;

Answer (score 17):

You can also add padding for a nice effect.

```
<img src="image.png" style="padding:1px;border:thin solid black;">
```

Answer (score 10):

I also prefer CSS over HTML; HTML is about content, CSS about presentation.

With CSS you have three options.

1. Inline CSS (like in Trevor's and Diodeus' solutions). Hard to maintain, and doesn't guarantee consistency: you'll have to check yourself that every image has the same border-width and border-color.
2. Internal stylesheet. Solves the consistency issue for all images on the page having class="hasBorder", but you'll have to include a stylesheet for each page, and again make sure "hasBorder" is defined the same each time.
3. External stylesheet. If you include a link to the external CSS file on each page *all* images with class="hasBorder" on all pages will have the same border.

Example using internal stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Image with border</title>

<style type="text/css">
  img.hasBorder { border:15px solid #66CC33; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
  <img class="hasBorder" src="peggy.jpg" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

If you want an external stylesheet, replace the <style>...</style> block with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somestylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: You're correct regarding inline styles.  I considered how to apply css outside the scope of the question, and used inline styling for brevity.

Answer (score 6):

`border="1"` ON IMAGE tag or using css `border:1px solid #000;`

Answer (score 6):

CSS

```
img{border:2px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Jack,

You can learn a great deal about borders, and how to use them at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp. That being said, there are a couple different ways you could accomplish this.

Below is how I generally do it, but reading the documentation on w3schools you may come upon your own desired method.

```
.addBorder {
  /* Thickness, Style, and Color */
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

<img src="mypicture.jpg" alt="My Picture" class="addBorder" />
```

**Edit:**

I noticed the original question was not "How to add a border to an image," but instead it was "how to add in a box around an image using html?" The question was re-written by others, so I'm not 100% sure you wanted a border on your image.

If you just wanted a box around your images, you could use a DIV, with it's own styles:

```
.imageBox {
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000000;
}

<div class="imageBox">
  <img src="picture.jpg" alt="My Picture" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way depends on whether you only want a specific image in your content to have a border or there is a pattern in your code where certain images need to have a border. In the first case, go with the style attribute on the img element, otherwise give it a meaningful class name and define that border in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

as said above simple line of code will fix your problems

```
border: 1px solid #000;
```

There is another option to add border to your image and that with photoshop you can see how it's done with this tutorial below:
http://bannercheapdesign.com/articles-and-tutorials/learn-how-to-add-border-to-your-banner-design-using-photoshop/

Comment: This is not a good answer, and it smells suspiciously like spam. *Five years* after the question was asked, and two years after marko's comment explaining why image editing answers are bad, you contribute only a link to a tutorial on how to use another proprietary software to do exactly the same thing. -1.

Answer (score -1):

The answers above are very good I'm sure. But for dim-wits, like me, I recommend Snagit 10. You can give an image a border in any width, style, and color before inserting it into your webpage. They do a full working program on 30 day trial.

Comment: which is of course fine until you want to restyle your website or repurpose the image. There's a good reason best practice is to separate content and presentation.